# Unable to fectch data from backend using express

Tags: node.js, express

Im not using postman because im on a beginner level im using the chrome to see data but the problem I'm facing is that all I can is a empty array. ------> [] on chrome screen

Here the route im using.

```
 router.get('/', asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
     // here i tried to remove this command and use 
    // and put instead 
    // res.send('what is wrong here...')
    // and i saw that rendring on chrome screen
  // there must be some problem here on below line
        const products = await Product.find({})
    
        res.json(products)
    }))
```

This is server.js file

```
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import colors from 'colors'
import connectDB from './config/db.js' 
import productRoutes from './routes/productRoutes.js'

dotenv.config()

connectDB()

const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('API is running...')
})
//here im using the route
app.use('/api/products', productRoutes)

const PORT = process.env.PORT  || 5000

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server is running ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold));
```

And here is the Product scheme

```
const productScheme = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    brand: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true,

    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,

    },
    reviews: [ reviewScheme ],
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0

    },
    numReviews: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0

    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0
    },
    countInStock: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productScheme)
```

Its getting frustrating as literally im a newb to this technology. I hope some out there tell me what the problem is here..

Comment: Have you added a product to your DB? I assume by the no post route and that you're not using postman that your DB is empty

Comment: i had deleted the DB while i was testing the command (npm run data:destroyed) I'm kinda feeling ashamed that i stuck on it BUT literally I thank you for your help Mohammed :))